# ELMAH error logging : the wrong error message is returned

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, elmah

I'm trying to use Elmah for error logging in my MVC application. But for some reason, it is reporting the wrong error.

I put following code in my Controller class to make sure an error occurs:

```
        int a = 0;
        int b = 10 / a;
```

As soon as this code is executed, an ErrorMail is sent, and this contains the following message:

**System.InvalidOperationException**: The view 'Error' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched: ~/Views/Home/Error.aspx ~/Views/Home/Error.ascx ~/Views/Shared/Error.aspx ~/Views/Shared/Error.ascx ~/Views/Home/Error.cshtml ~/Views/Home/Error.vbhtml ~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml ~/Views/Shared/Error.vbhtml

But a view is correctly generated. So I don't get to see the real exception, only the "fake" one above.

I have following web.config file:

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
  <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
</sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<elmah>
  <errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/App_Data" />
  <errorMail from="noreply@website.com"
         to="me@mycompany.com"
         cc="you@mycompany.com"
         bcc="bcc@mycompay.com"
         subject="elmah error mail" />
  <security allowRemoteAccess="true" />
<!--elmah-->
</elmah>

<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/GeneralError">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/Http404" />
</customErrors>
```

As you can see, I'm using a different page for a 404-error, and a General Error (which is simply: all the rest). I have an ErrorController, with these two methods:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Http404()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult GeneralError()
    {
        return View();
    }
 }
```

If I use the standard "Error.aspx" in the Shared folder, I do get to see the correct page, but no ErrorMail is being sent, so I take it that Elmah isn't handling the exception.

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong? Do I need to post some more code?

Thanks a lot for any help you can give me.

Comment: Do you have an `Error` controller?

Comment: Yes. It has two methods, a "GeneralError" which simply returns a view
(the view is located in "~/Error/GeneralError.aspx") and a "Http404" with view Http404.aspx)

Should I change these views to be partial views?

Comment: I've updated my question just to be sure

Answer (score 0):

From the message ~/Views/Home/Error.aspx it looks like its trying to find a view called error.aspx which I think is in the shared/ folder by default when creating an MVC3 site..

Maybe you should look at :

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/07/14/asp-net-mvc-preview-4-release-part-1.aspx

Comment: Yes, the "Error.aspx" is in the Shared folder by default. If I create such a file (with "hello world" in it, for instance), then that file is showed to the user

But the ErrorMail and the Elmah logging no longer occurs.